# Is there a way to map a virtual directory for *.asmx methods in ASP.Net 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, json, asmx

A little while ago, I managed to get WebServices to return JSON as well as XML from the code-behind of an ASPX.

Today, I needed to migrate an existing **ASMX** WebService to return JSON instead of XML (which was accomplished with little fuss). My problem became evident in testing the new method.

In the code-behind for the ASMX, I created a new method to return JSON instead of XML.
The method works, in that it returns the expected JSON however the new routine breaks every XML-returning method in the code-behind (they all throw "`System.NotSupportedException: The type System.Collections.Hashtable is not supported because it implements IDictionary.`" which is unexpected because the return types are all defined as `XmlDocument`).

If I simply comment out the JSON-returning method, the XML-returning methods function normally. Uncommenting out the JSON-returning method breaks the XML-returning methods again.

While I cannot find any supporting documentation anywhere, this behavior leads me to believe that in ASP.Net 2.0, JSON-returning methods cannot co-exist in the same module as XML-returning methods.

This led me to try separating the methods in sub-classes like so:

```
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempura.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ScriptService()> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class MyWebServices
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <ScriptService()> _
    Public Class xml
        Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

        <WebMethod()> _
        <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Xml)> _
        Public Function MethodName As XmlDocument
            ...
        End Function
    End Class

    <ScriptService()> _
    Public Class json
        Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

        <WebMethod()> _
        <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
        Public Function MethodName As Hashtable
            ...
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```

The idea being that I could then call the services in one of the following manners:

- `~/MyWebServices.asmx/xml/MethodName`
- `~/MyWebServices.asmx/xml.MethodName`
- `~/MyWebServices.asmx/json/MethodName`
- `~/MyWebServices.asmx/json.MethodName`

This unfortunately didn't work, giving a 404-Not Found error.

I could simply throw all the JSON-returning methods into a different ASMX, but I am hoping for a better way.

My questions are thus:

- Is there a way to accomplish `~/MyWebServices.asmx/xml/MethodName` and `~/MyWebServices.asmx/json.MethodName`? I like the idea of separating functions by return type in a virtual path.
- Failing that, is there a way to get JSON-returning methods to co-exist in the same module as XML-returning methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to @smartcaveman for the attempt.

The solution to this was a different (and I think better, overall) approach. Instead of explicitly returning either an `XMLDocument` (XML) or a `HashTable` (JSON), I instead wrote out a custom return object like so:

```
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempura.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ScriptService()> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class MyWebServices
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    <ScriptMethod()> _
    Public Function MethodName As CustomReturnObject
        ...
    End Function

End Class
```

I made sure that the custom return object implemented `IXmlSerializable` and now the Framework returns XML **or** JSON depending on the caller.

If the caller specifies a `contentType` of `application/xml`, XML is returned.

If the caller specifies a `contentType` of `application/json`, JSON is returned.

I think this approach is better in that I don't have to organize WebServices by return type, nor do I have to maintain two separate methods (one XML, one JSON) for each WebService I write.

Thanks for at least looking.

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised to find out that you're correct about this limitation, however it applies only to .asmx Script Services.  You can still return any kind (and combination) of content-types you want with ASP.NET 2.0+ in general.

I found this article that explains these limitations and clarifies misconceptions about ASMX/JSON: 
http://encosia.com/asmx-and-json-common-mistakes-and-misconceptions/ .  The relevant excerpt says:

> "As I alluded to earlier, the one stipulation is that these ScriptServices only return JSON serialized results if they are requested properly. Otherwise, even a service marked with the attribute will return XML instead of JSON. I can only assume that’s part of the reason for the misconception that ASMX services cannot respond with JSON."

Comment: I'm familiar with both the article and the site :) The problem is not that I cannot return JSON. The problem is that I apparently cannot get JSON-returning methods to co-exist in the same module as XML-returning methods.